# how to send values to snowflake procedures array_construct field

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
 EXECUTION 
        try:
            session = self.get_session()
            session.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
            if with_result:
                output = session.execute(query, values)
                result = output.mappings().all()
            session.execute("commit;")
            print("result = ", result)
            return result

FUNCTION 
 def insert_data(self, data ):
        y = list(data)
        values = {'data_assets': [y]}
        query = "call data_table(:data_assets);"
        self.database.execute_query(query,values)
        
PROCEDURE
create or replace data_table(data_val array)
returns Table()
language sql
{code}

  
VALUE PASSED TO THE FUNCTION
        k = {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","EMAIL"],"id":1,"size":50,"pers_id": 081945}', '{"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","PHONE_NO"],"id":1,"size":70,"pers_id": 081945}', '{"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","MANAGER","USER"],"id":1,"size":40,"pers_id": 081945} ', '{"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","VIN"],"id":1,"size":120,"pers_id": 081945}', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","USER"],"id":1,"size":500,"pers_id": 081945} ', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PII","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","USER"],"id":1,"size":20,"pers_id": 081945}', '{"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL ","EMAIL","EMPLOYEE","USER"],"id":1,"size":70,"pers_id": 081945} ', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","US_PHONE_NO"],"id":1,"size":80,"pers_id": 081945}', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","LOCATION"],"id":1,"size":5,"pers_id": 081945}', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","ADDRESS","USER"],"id":1,"size":90,"pers_id": 081945}', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL_MAIL","ADMIN"],"id":1,"size":1,"pers_id": 081945} '
```

ERROR:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 59 unexpected '"path"'.
syntax error line 1 at position 76 unexpected '['.
syntax error line 1 at position 87 unexpected ','.
syntax error line 1 at position 134 unexpected ']'.

[SQL: call data_table(%(data_assets)s);]
[parameters: {'data_assets': [['{"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL  _MAIL","EMAIL"],"id":1,"size":50,"pers_id": 081945}', '{"datasour ... (1200 characters truncated) ... 081945}', ' {"path":["CATEGORY","PERSONAL  ","EMAIL","PERSONAL  _MAIL","ADMIN"],"id":1,"size":1,"pers_id": 081945} ']]}]

not able to pass parameter to array field(in procedures)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list as an [Array Constant](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#label-array-constant). I don't know how one can use [binding variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#binding-data).

```
ary = list(k)
query = f"call proc({ary})"
self.database.execute_query(query)
```

Comment: i tried as mentioned still getting errors

Comment: Looks like SQL Alchemy is not accepting the JSON. It does not appear to be in proper JSON form. For example, this appears to be an array of Path, etc., entries. The array should be enclosed in [ ]. Also, there are issues with the PERS_ID columns: SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted. Finally, don't pass a new JSON values to the procedure. Instead, pass the list y to the procedure.